# why does python not drop all duplicates?

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, drop-duplicates

This is my 
[original data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0xmq.png)

I want to remove the duplicates for the columns 'head_x' and 'head_y' and the columns 'cost_x' and 'cost_y'.

This is my code:

```
df=df.astype(str)

df.drop_duplicates(subset={'head_x','head_y'}, keep=False, inplace=True)

df.drop_duplicates(subset={'cost_x','cost_y'}, keep=False, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

This is [the output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrYUR.png), as you can see the first row is a duplicate on both subsets. So why is this row stil there?

I do not just want to remove the first row but all duplicates. [Tis is another output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/136RR.png) where also for Index/Node 6 there is a duplicate.

Comment: Please do not post images of data. This makes it more difficult for people to help you! Just paste it in as text. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the first 2 rows:

```
      head_x  cost_x  head_y  cost_y
Node
1          2       6       2       3
1          2       6       3       4
```

Start from *head_x* and *head_y*:

- from the first row are *2* and *2*,
- from the second row are *2* and *3*,

so these two pairs are **different**.

Then look at *cost_x* and *cost_y*:

- from the first row are *6* and *3*,
- from the second row are *6* and *4*,

so these two pairs are also **different**.

Conclusion: These 2 rows are **not** duplicates, taking into account both column
subsets.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=df.astype(str)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset={'head_x','head_y'}, keep=False, inplace=True)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset={'cost_x','cost_y'}, keep=False, inplace=True)
```

## I assume that cost_x should be replaced with head_y, in other way there are no duplicates